# Jenkins Job-DSL job to pass parameters to jenkins-pipeline while job creation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a `CI Seed Job` DSL Job in jenkins which creates a jenkins pipeline job.Is there any possibilities to get parameters in `CI Seed Job` and pass the input parameters given in Seed job to the jenkins pipeline script.

Here in below example, how the `schema name` given as parameter can be updated in jenkins pipeline job when creating it

```
CI Seed Job Setup: 

 1. Configured one string parameter `SchemaName`
 2. DSL Script for jenkins pipeline job creation 
pipelineJob('job-name') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script('''
        pipeline {
            agent any
                stages {
                    stage('Stage 1') {
                        steps {
                echo $SchemaName
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Stage 2') {
                        steps {
                            echo 'logic'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      '''.stripIndent())
      sandbox()     
    }
  }
}
```